# Add the time variable to a filter (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, google-places-api

I'm working with google places API and in the VC where I want to show the nearby places, I created a filter for the places I'm going to download

```
if response.status == "OK" {
                if let placesDownloaded = response.places {
                    var number = numberPlaces / (categories?.count)!
                    number = number == 0 ? 1 : number

                    let firstPlace = placesDownloaded.prefix(1)

                    var isRestaurant = false


                    for place in firstPlace {
                        for type in place.types! {
                            if (type.lowercased() == "restaurant") {
                                isRestaurant = true
                            }
                        }
                    }
                        if(isRestaurant) {
                                number = 1
                            }

                            places.append(contentsOf: placesDownloaded.prefix(number))
                        }
```

Now I would like to add the "time" variable to this filter (for example `if (type.lowercased() == "restaurant" &&` the time on user position is 12.00 o'clock){} etc.) but I really don't know how can I do, can someone make me an example of how can I add the time var and use it in this filter?

Comment: Do you want something like restaurant open/close? or anything else, describe use or anything or it.

Comment: @DipakKacha no, i want to know how can i use the exact time (on the user position) like a var in this filter

Comment: What the problem with getting current date from system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by using NSDateformatter as given below,

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.timezone = TimeZone.current
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm"
print(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate()))
```